Estimating Variability or Volatility at a Point in Discrete Signal
I have a discrete signal/time series $X_t$ whose values were recorded from a sensor at a semi-regular frequency. I want to create some measure of variability/volatility/noise at each timestamp. I've considered a sliding window to compute the standard deviation at each timestamp and the results are decent, but wanted to know if there were any other approaches.
I'm familiar with ARCH/GARCH, but I'm not sure that the model assumptions apply here (the signal is more sinusoidal in nature).

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

You have added the discrete-data tag. Are your values discrete, e.g. round numbers? Or did you mean discrete time? If the latter, please remove the tag.

You're right -- updated!
